# Burninating [geojason] - this is really just [geojson], right?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Recently I've been fixing questions that contain the string "Jason" but should, instead, contain ["JSON"](http://www.json.org/).

I have just found the tag **[geojason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geojason)** with 11 questions.  I *assume* that should be [geojson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geojson) with 1,613 questions.  Before I retag those 11 questions, I'd like to confirm I'm not making a mistake here.

Comment: From a quick search, it seems to be a pun based on the library's author being named [Jason](http://geojason.info/about/). Burnination is probably fine, but a tag synonym is also possible perhaps.

Comment: @4castle That doesn't look like a library, just the blog's pun title.

Comment: Synonym would be better IMO, that would stop it from being recreated the next time a user with more than 1500 rep misspells the library name in the tag field.

Comment: @4castle - suggesting a synonym seems reasonable.  "Jason" for "JSON" seems to come regularly.  But, I don't have the requisite score in [tag:geojason] to suggest the synonym.

Comment: No one does, the tag hasn't been abused enough to allow a synonym to be created. It is a defect in the tag system that no one has yet cared to fix. You'll need a moderator to do it.

Comment: If you explain that the community cannot create a synonym request in this situation, then tag this [tag:support] and [tag:synonym-request] a moderator or staff member will see it.

Comment: @TinyGiant - maybe I misunderstood because I haven't done this before.  Does one need a 5 score in [tag:geojson] or [tag:geojason] to replace the latter with the former?  Because there are members with the requisite score in [tag:geojson] - just not me.

Comment: I've merged and syn'd geojason into geojson